# Can an Access macro be saved as an add-in to be used in another Access database?

Tags: vba, ms-access, add-in

I am doing some work within MS Access and I have come across a rather annoying hurdle. I have written up some code and created a macro to execute said code. My issue is that I would like to be able to execute this macro from any project.

As of right now the only way I can run the macro/code for a new project is to create a new module paste in the code and then create a new macro to run said code. Is there a way to capture this macro/code into an addin or save the macro globally so that it is available any time an access project is open?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reference to an Access database in the same way as any other reference. Once you do, you can run any code it contains.